# C++ EnumWindows does somtimes not return a window title

Tags: c++, windows

When I run the code I posted below, I noticed two things:

1. Sometimes `GetWindowText(hWND, title, length);` does not return a title. Just an empty string, although `hWND != NULL`. And secondly
2. When I do not interact with a window for some minutes, its name will, too, not appear in the console output.

So what is going on here? Is this some Windows thing, that windows get "inactive" after some time or something like that?

EDIT: `GetLastError()` returns 0 if called right after `GetWindowText`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumCallbackFunction(HWND hWND, LPARAM lParam);

int main()
{
    EnumWindows(EnumCallbackFunction, NULL);
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumCallbackFunction(HWND hWND, LPARAM lParam) {

    int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWND) + 1;
    wchar_t* title = new wchar_t[length];

    GetWindowText(hWND, title, length);
 
    std::wcout << "title: " << title << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

Example output:

```
title:
title:
title: GDI+ Window (VCTIP.EXE)
title: .NET-BroadcastEventWindow.4.0.0.0.1400c58.0
title:
title:
title:
title:
title: (C/C++) EnumWindows does somtimes not return a window title - Stack Overflow
```

Comment: Please note that there is no such language as C/C++. They are two seperate languages. I have edited your question to remove references to C as the code is C++.

Comment: Check the return value of `GetWindowText` and use `GetLastError` if an error occured to see why it fails.

Comment: Quick update: `GetLastError` returns 0. `GetWindowText` gives me a bunch of numbers. I will look into them. Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of hidden top level windows with no titles.  Use the Spy++ tool (with MSVS)  to see all Windows.

Comment: `GetWindowTextLength` _"...If the window has no text, the return value is zero...."_ see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengthw

Comment: Note that hidden windows also exist, e.g. InputOnly windows or event windows. Maybe check if a window is actually shown and only get the title of those?

Comment: The API works [as designed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextw). The expectations are wrong.

Comment: [The secret life of GetWindowText](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030821-00/?p=42833).